# Finding approximately matching rows of numerical data in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, matching, bigdata

As a toy example consider the following, where we have real data `x`, `y` perturbed versions of `x` and `z` which cointains the mixed rows:

```
x = matrix(1:100, nrow = 100, ncol= 4 , byrow = FALSE)
y = x + matrix( .001 * rnorm(n = 400), nrow = 100, ncol= 4)
z = rbind(x,y)
z = z[sample(nrow(z)),]
```

How can we find or estimate the matching rows in `z` efficiently in R? At best I would like to get just the rows that belong to `x` or for each row just the one from `x` or `y` but not both.  I have looked at the package `RecordLinkage` but mabye in the purely numerical case there exist more efficient solutions. Furthermore in my setting I have 100K+ rows and 20 columns and a call to `compare.dedup` on the full data set needs far too much memory.

EDIT: I tried the approach suggested:

```
setseed(100)
x = matrix( 1:100, nrow = 100, ncol= 4 ,byrow = FALSE)
y = x + matrix( .001 * rnorm(n = 400), nrow = 100, ncol= 4)
z = rbind(x,y)

#z = z[sample(nrow(z)),]


res = caret::findLinearCombos(t(z))
res$remove%>%sort
```

the result is shown below. We see that we get 8.0 as well as the perturbed 8.00572 - the same with 9 and 10. It works with some pairs but not in general.

> > z[res$remove,1]%>% sort
> >     [1]   2.000000   3.000000   4.000000   4.000952   5.000000   5.001135   6.000000   6.000008   7.000000   7.001225  [11]   8.000000   8.000572   8.997471   9.000000  10.000000  10.000135  10.999871  11.000000  12.000000  12.000113  [21]  12.999917  13.000000  13.998705  14.000000  15.000000  15.001787  16.000000  16.002099  17.000000  17.000232  [31]  18.000000  18.000062  19.000000  19.000354  20.000000  20.000725  21.000000  21.000268  21.999909  22.000000  [41]  22.999861  23.000000  24.000000  24.001042  25.000000  25.000478  26.000000  26.000567  27.000000  27.000610  [51]  27.999102  28.000000  29.000000  29.000263  30.000000  30.001195  31.000000  31.000267  32.000000  32.000999  [61]  33.000000  33.001137  34.000000  34.000603  35.000000  35.001352  36.000000  36.001945  36.998791  37.000000  [71]  38.000000  38.003187  38.999596  39.000000  39.997090  40.000000  40.999639  41.000000  42.000000  42.000220  [81]  43.000000  43.000062  44.000000  44.000170  45.000000  45.000222  45.998763  46.000000  47.000000  47.001132  [91]  47.999887  48.000000  49.000000  49.002185  50.000000  50.000743  51.000000  51.002065  52.000000  52.001307 [101]  52.998977  53.000000  53.999975  54.000000  54.999356  55.000000  56.000000  56.001569  57.000000  57.000013 [111]  58.000000  58.001158  58.999849  59.000000  59.999147  60.000000  61.000000  61.001045  61.999888  62.000000 [121]  62.998223  63.000000  63.999040  64.000000  64.998698  65.000000  66.000000  66.000069  66.999729  67.000000 [131]  68.000000  68.000566  69.000000  69.000426  69.998899  70.000000  71.000000  71.000105  71.999957  72.000000 [141]  73.000000  73.000644  73.999902  74.000000  74.999892  75.000000  76.000000  76.000321  77.000000  77.000765 [151]  78.000000  78.000649  78.999644  79.000000  79.998975  80.000000  80.998300  81.000000  82.000000  82.001297 [161]  82.998977  83.000000  83.998629  84.000000  84.999534  85.000000  85.998803  86.000000  87.000000  87.001064 [171]  87.999871  88.000000  88.998835  89.000000  89.998987  90.000000  91.000000  91.001467  92.000000  92.001252 [181]  93.000000  93.000839  93.998372  94.000000  94.999120  95.000000  95.999964  96.000000  96.999911  97.000000 [191]  98.000000  98.002148  99.000000  99.000914 100.000000 100.001824

Answer (score 1):

the **caret** package has a function  **findLinearCombos()** which helps you identify linear dependencies among columns of a matrix (by omitting rows and computing the rank each time), in your case you want to transpose your matrix. I would give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't this used to reduce the number of columns and not the number of rows?

Comment: that's why I suggested to transpose your matrix to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Yes, I oversaw that. Thank you, I will think about it! Does it work with noise too?

Comment: I have used it to reduce the number of columns used for decision trees. it certainly works with noise since the linear combinations do not have to be perfect.

Comment: Pointing to caret is great. The function maxDissim could help too! thank you!

Comment: here is a useful illustration https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/findLinearCombos.html

Comment: please see my edit. Did I understand something wrong? I am afraid that the noise prevents the approach from